# PhpMyAdmin error 500

Tags: phpmyadmin, directadmin

I have a dedicated server and my host provider did install directAdmin on it.

I've created a new user and assigned an IP and a domain using directAdmin; then I did create a new mysql user and visit phpmyadmin.

When I visit phpmyadmin, it will work and show me pages `but do not execute any of my requests` and will show this popup everytime.

There's error says:

> Error in processing request
>
> Error code 500
>
> Error text : Internal server error

This picture show the main page of phpmyadmin :

[image: error display]

Would you tell me how can I fix this?

***UPDATE :***

I checked permission and owner of phpmyadmin and these setting was OK.
Owner is `webapp` and permission is OK.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Check the logfiles on the server or contact your host provider for support, seems  like a misconfiguration.

Comment: where can I find log files? Should I use linux shell or directadmin to findout them?

Comment: you host provider maybe provide documentation & troubleshooting to such problems. Google it with name of your hosting provider. You will find something

Answer (score 0):

I faced the problem. My php version was **7.2**. Actually this error from a phpmyadmin library. The library is  **/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php**. In this file line no **614**. So you need to modify the file

**From** && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*')))

**to**  && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))

or you can replace full method bellow:

```
/**
* Function to check whether to remember the sorting order or not
*
* @param array $analyzed_sql_results the analyzed query and other variables set
*                                    after analyzing the query
*
* @return boolean
*/
function PMA_isRememberSortingOrder($analyzed_sql_results)
{
return $GLOBALS['cfg']['RememberSorting']
    && ! ($analyzed_sql_results['is_count']
        || $analyzed_sql_results['is_export']
        || $analyzed_sql_results['is_func']
        || $analyzed_sql_results['is_analyse'])
    && $analyzed_sql_results['select_from']
    && ((empty($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']))
        || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
            && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))
    && count($analyzed_sql_results['select_tables']) == 1;
}
```

I hope this may help. Thank you.

Comment: when I change the pagination of my database to 14 or up, it keep showing the same error 500 even though I tried out with your code above